# MVC Partial view to register button control action is Not applicable

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I am use MVC Partial view .I have a two of Page AddPoll.cshtml and Listpoll.cshtml. page AddPoll.cshtml use Partial view.
I use AddPoll:partial view page to be placed a partial view with Listpoll.

```
@Html.Partial("/Areas/admin/Views/Poll/AddPoll.cshtml",new Mvc_baker.Areas.admin.Models.pollquestion());
```

AddPoll.cshtml

```
@model Mvc_baker.Areas.admin.Models.pollquestion

<link href="~/Content/bootstrapvalidform.css" rel="stylesheet" />
@using (Html.BeginForm(actionName: "AddPoll", controllerName: "Poll"))
{
  @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
  <form class="">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="panel panel-primary">
        <label class="control-label">پرسش</label>
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.QuestionText, new { id = "Name",style="width:450px", @class = "form-control" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.QuestionText)
        <input class="btn btn-primary btn-default" name="commit" value="register" type="submit">
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
}
```

When I click the register button control action is Not applicable

When the breakpoint action on control and I can not run

Comment: <form action="/Poll/AddPoll" class=""> is this working?

Comment: I've tested did not differ

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have 2 nested html forms which is invalid markup. The `Html.BeginForm` helper already generates a `<form>` tag. So you should get rid of the inner form.

```
@model Mvc_baker.Areas.admin.Models.pollquestion

<link href="~/Content/bootstrapvalidform.css" rel="stylesheet" />

@using (Html.BeginForm(actionName: "AddPoll", controllerName: "Poll"))
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="panel panel-primary">
            <label class="control-label">پرسش</label>
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.QuestionText, new { id = "Name",style="width:450px", @class = "form-control" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.QuestionText)
            <input class="btn btn-primary btn-default" name="commit" value="register" type="submit" />
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

Comment: I deleted my form but did not change